# Lazy loading issue in UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have implemented lazy loading in my UITableView,

in which, i am downloading images from server, and server contains images with different  sizes..

and displays like this,

[image]:
Images getting displayed properly but **the problem is UITableViewCell Text is not getting displayed properly align in single line** as you can see in the image alignment of `UITableViewCell Text` is not in the single line

**Means:Cell 0 to Cell 4 is displayed properly because server contains images with size of 100*100 for Cell 0 to Cell 4 but alignment of cell 5 and cell 6 is different  because server contains image with different size of 85*85**

Is there any way in which i can set Text alignment in single line ??

***Thanks in advance.***

Comment: why you not using custom cell..? and set Height  of cell according to text

Comment: Don't you think custom will be slow, compare to this ?

Comment: Check this http://www.highoncoding.com/Videos/823_Creating_a_Custom_UITableViewCell.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i Suggest you to use Custom table-cell with One `image-view` and **Label** and set Imageview contentMode like bellow

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill; //will fill the frame

imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;  //will show the entire image, possibly leaving areas of the frame open.
```

**and your Label set Number of Line 0**

Answer (score 0):

I think Custom TableView Cell will do for you. 
You can design a cell like below
https://www.dropbox.com/s/r9r6dsmdwmpk50h/customcell.png

Comment: Custom TableView Cell is working properly, but how to set dynamic height of UIImageView ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use
 imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

to adjust the imagview width and height based on image size